# JAVA synchronize operations between threads using classes

Tags: java, synchronization, client-server, wait

I am currently trying to create sort of a reliable UDP protocol where my server sends packets of 1024 bytes each to my client, when it finishes a send/receive cycle the server waits and the client sends a command over TCP to the server that tells it what packets were not received (I am using the first 2 bytes as a packet id [of type short]), the server than is notified by a remote class and sends the missing packets.

```
private void waitUntilNotified() {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting..." + new Date());
            waiting = true;
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Stop waiting");
    }
}

public void notifyThis(){
    synchronized (this) {
        if(waiting){
            waiting = false;
            notify();
            System.out.println("Notified " + new Date());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes on local testing the command arrives before the server starts waiting, therefore causes it to wait forever.

I was wandering if there was a foolproof way of making sure that even if the command that triggers `notifyThis()` comes before the server triggers the `waitUntilNotified()` function it will still notify it and change the waiting status?

If anything is unclear just comment and I'll try to explain it.

TL:DR, I am looking for a way to call `notify()` only after the server starts to `wait()` even if the call is made before it starts waiting

Comment: Is it possible for you to check if command has arrived or not before starting wait?
If yes then start wait only if command has not arrived.

Comment: The command is read in another class, when it arrives the class calls 'notifyThis()' on the server object, that is why i have the boolean waiting, sadly i can't do this the other way around.

Comment: Why not just use TCP since it is designed to be reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like what you *really* need is a higher level concurrency primitive.  Here are some possibilities:

- [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) .... most likely
- [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)
- [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

or possibly some kind of `Queue` or `Deque`.

---

The problem (for us) is that we can't see how you are actually using your wait / notify methods, so it is not clear what you really need.

But as a *general principle* it is better in the long term to identify and use an appropriate higher-level concurrency class than to try to implement your own concurrency from the basic building blocks.

And ... as @D.B notes ... implementing your own "reliable" transport over the top of UDP is reinventing the wheel.  TCP is the obvious alternative, and if you are doing this to get "better than TCP" performance, there are other alternatives.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have imlemented a blocking queue and a check whenever it tries to notify the server.
About using TCP: 
I am a CS student and the point of this project was to learn more about how things work, I know that TCP is the obvious alternative, but making something of my own is way more enriching.

Comment: *"... but making something of my own is way more enriching."* - Have you ever considered building a pyramid?  That would be "mega enriching" :-)  But seriously, I don't think you will understand how TCP will work by trying to reimplement it *ab initio*.  Better to read the specifications.

Comment: That actually sounds like a great idea for a project :D

Comment: But I was curious what are the "better than tcp alternatives"? @Stephen C

Comment: Thank you, definitely going to check some of those out.